# Iterm2 x Powerlevel10K new line shows only >

Tags: iterm2, iterm

i have this weird issue with my new iterm and powerlevel10k

after configuring it, it shows new "entered" lines as ">" instead of the UI.

as seen here:

[image]

why doesn't it show the "entered" lines as the block of `[~/GIT]> cd ..` for example?

Answer (score 0):

it is an intended and configurable behavior of the PowerLevel10k.
You configure it in [configuration-wizard](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#configuration-wizard) during the first run of the PowerLevel10.
Also, it is still possible to reconfigure current config with  the command: `p10k configure`.

[image]